# What is the correct way to transclude HTML content in Angular?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-transclude

I need to transclude a `div` containing a logout button into one of my custom select dropdown directives, but the transcluded content doesn't end up inside the directive template, but rather outside. If I just put a piece of string, for example `Some content` inside the directive instead of the HTML, then the transclude works. But as soon as I put HTML it just refuses to work.

So my question is what is the correct and most simple way of transcluding HTML content into a directive template?

Directive:

```
coForms.directive('coSelect', [function() {

    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: {},
        transclude: true,
        controller: 'CoFormsCtrl',
        controllerAs: 'co',
        templateUrl: 'app/views/components/co-forms/co-select.html',
        link: function(scope, element, attrs, ctrl) {


        }
    };
}]);
```

Usage:

```
<!-- This is inside a loop, where it should only appear for the first row, hence the ng-if="$first" -->
<co-select>
    <div ng-if="$first" class="logout-wrapper">
        <a ng-href="/logout">
            <button class="btn-danger plain">Logout</button>
        </a>
    </div>
</co-select>
```

Template:

```
<div>
  <ul>
    <li>The options list yo</li>
  </ul>
  <!-- Transcluded content should go here -->
  <div ng-transclude></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Could you please provide a plunk, at a quick glance the transclusion looks ok

Comment: What is `ng-if="$first"` supposed to achieve? Remove that, or set a condition that evaluates to true and your transclusion works just fine. If you want to transclude the content only in the first iteration of a loop in the template then I think you need to test $first outside the transclusion.

Comment: @Duncan I added a comment to why the $first is there.

Comment: Works OK in [this JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jg47L1de/).